# MHX2 Import addon in Blender preferences

Tags: add-on, import, makehuman

I am having an issue with installing the MHX2 MakeHuman addon in Blender 2.76.  Under my user preferences, no MakeHuman option is listed.  I've extracted the MHX2 folder into the Addons directory, moved it there manually, taken the two main folders out and put them in separately, created a MakeHuman folder to place both in, and so far nothing is showing up when I run Blender.  Has anyone had this issue and know how to work around it?

Comment: place the zip in there and locate it from prefs

Answer (score 1):

See the installation instructions at https://bitbucket.org/ThomasMakeHuman/mhx2-makehuman-exchange

You only need to copy the `import_runtime_mhx2` subfolder to the addons folder, not the entire archive.

Answer (score 0):

If the addon came zipped, in most cases you can just go to the Blender preferences, and click install from file. Just navigate to the .zip file and double click it.